# Getting the latest post and comments from a facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I want to get latest post and comments from a particular page.

The below code gets all the posts and comments of that page using graph api explorer

```cs
 var accessToken = hdnaccesstoken.Value;//page access token
 var client = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
 dynamic result = client.Get("me", new { fields = "name,id,posts" });
```

My requirement is to get the latest(30 mins for example) posts and comments, how can I be able to achieve that.

Comment: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results." See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: I am still a beginner on this site. Now i got it

Answer (score 0):

The best practise is to do that using fql(facebook query language)

```
var resultpost = client.Get("fql",
                    new { q = "SELECT message,created_time,actor_id,post_id FROM stream WHERE source_id = " + feed + " and created_time > " + timestamp });
```

where created_time is the column which will filter out the unnecessary post from the output.